# How to get MySQL Database option as a Data Source in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, mysql

I  am very new to MySQL and .NET as well. I am currently creating a web site using those 
I'd like to get some suggestions for my doubts...

Is this possible to have MySQL Database option as a Data Source in Visual Studion 2008? I am using the MySQL connector Net 5.1.2 since 6.1.5 supports VS 2010 only.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I am using 6.1.5 with MS-VS2008 it's totally stable and supported.
read the documentation more! easy and samples already provided.

Comment: Thaks a lot.. I am ok now with the Connector 5.2.7 :)

Comment: connector 5.2.7! missing nice bug fix regarding concurrent calls of stored procedure, i strongly recommend to use 6.1.5 in case you use stored procedures. please check change log in mysql website to get more info.